# Deleting a particular element from a nested table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a type of nested table like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRING_ARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
```

And I want to have some ways to remove a particular element from the array.
E.g.

```
AVC_NAMES := STRING_ARRAY('ALEX', 'BETTY', 'CARL', 'DONALD');
SP_EXCLUDE(AVC_NAMES, 'BETTY'); // this will remove BETTY from the array.
```

Is there any build-in methods in the nested table that can remove specific element from an array? Or should I write a s.p. to do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Multiset](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators006.htm) operator. Multisete operators combine the results of two nested tables into a single nested table.

`result := collection1 MULTISET EXCEPT collection2`

```
declare 
 type mycollection is table of varchar2(10);
  c1 mycollection := mycollection('A','B','C','D','E');
  to_remove mycollection := mycollection('C');
begin 
  c1 := c1 multiset EXCEPT  to_remove; 
for i                  in c1.first..c1.last
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c1(i));
  end loop;      
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this below snipet helps.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lv number_ntt;
  lv_out number_ntt;
  rem_value NUMBER:='&Enter_val';
BEGIN
  lv:=number_ntt(1,2,3,4,5,6);
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE BULK COLLECT
  INTO lv_out
  FROM TABLE(lv)
  WHERE COLUMN_VALUE NOT IN (rem_value);

  lv:=lv_out;
  FOR i                  IN lv.FIRST..lv.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(lv(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: But isn't `lv` still containing the removed value?

Comment: Yes it does. But just for illustration i have used lv_out. You can use lv only for out variable.

Comment: For better pictue i have edited the answer plz check